# Auto completion in jhipster dropdown list (angular 4)

Tags: angular, jhipster

I would like to implement auto completion feature in jhipster generated (angular 4)  dropdown list (user list)

Should i use any additional packages such as ng2-select-view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any non-trivial app will need advanced UI components, auto completion in dropdown list might be your first need but I'd bet it won't be the last one.

So, I'd suggest that you consider using a full UI lib rather than assembling components from various origins that require more work to integrate.

I've had good success using [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) with JHipster, alternatives like Angular Material and Clarity were not complete 6 months ago, I haven't checked since.

Only drawback is that JHipster templates use Bootstrap responsive grid system and PrimeNG comes with its own which is very close. So ideally, you would want to rewrite the `col-*` classes to `ui-g-*` but I found that PrimeNG widgets can coexist with Bootstrap grid when using Bootstrap theme.

Comment: Thanks Gaël Marziou .  PrimeNG does the job for me. Its awesome